# Creating a custom component in wordpress with 3 page layout

Tags: wordpress

I want to include a component in home page of my wordpress site
https://imgur.com/a/jVIu7

How can I create a cms part to enable my user upload image text so that it will be managed by him. I dont know how to search in google using the right term

Answer (score 1):

add a new plugin Page Builder

https://wordpress.org/plugins/siteorigin-panels/

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at https://www.advancedcustomfields.com.

I use it for all my clients sites. Allows you to have a client side CMS interface with instructions, labels etc, that then plugs into your theme or template.